# Angular Firebase IOS not pushing

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push

I am required to intergrate Push notifications for both android and IOS using angular Firebase.

I am currently using the video and article: 
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-native-with-firebase-fcm-push-notifications-ios-android/#Step-3-Broadcast-Messages

Right now, I am having difficulty receiving the notifications on my IOS device.

So far, Android works perfectly. However, when I use the firebase console to push to my iPhone, nothing happens.

Both android and iOS store tokens in firestore.

All the bundle IDs are correct and I followed the steps precicesly to ensure that the right certificates are set up.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

My steps:

1)

```
ionic start projectname
```

2) *blank project*

3) *chose not to use ionic 4*

4) *chose "y" (yes) for android and iOS integration*

5) cd ./projectname

6)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase
```

7)

```
npm install --save angularfire2 firebase
```

8) Adjusted the typescript files accordingly using the tutorial

9) Install rxjs to fix "Object(...)" error

```
npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat
import rxjs-compact to file

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operators';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50447449/6567753

10) Placed GoogleService-Info.plist and google services into the root folder of the project (Where config.xml is)

11) Built Android (works great)

```
ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

12) Added IOS and sorted certificates and provisional profiles using: https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

13) Using the firebase console and database, both apps store tokens.

**At this point Android pushes - IOS does not**

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

*app.components.ts below*

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

    import { FcmProvider } from '../providers/fcm/fcm';

    import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
    import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      rootPage:any = HomePage;

      constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,fcm: FcmProvider, toastCtrl: ToastController) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {

          // Get a FCM token
          fcm.getToken()

          // Listen to incoming messages
          fcm.listenToNotifications().pipe(
            tap(msg => {
              // show a toast
              const toast = toastCtrl.create({
                message: msg.body,
                duration: 3000
              });
              toast.present();
            })
          )
          .subscribe()

          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
          statusBar.styleDefault();
          splashScreen.hide();
        });
      }
    }
```

*app.module.ts below*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { FcmProvider } from '../providers/fcm/fcm';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat';

const firebase = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBoxPRJt3_i0UFnIBc4MZGFqq7daVy6t_o",
  authDomain: "b13webwrapper.firebaseio.com",
  databaseURL: "https://b13webwrapper.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "b13webwrapper",
  storageBucket: "b13webwrapper.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "456561976577"

 // your firebase web config
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebase), 
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Firebase,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    FcmProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*home.ts below*

For some reason Android will not push without reusing "fcm.getToken()" block in home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { FcmProvider } from '../../providers/fcm/fcm';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public fcm: FcmProvider,public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    // Get a FCM token
    this.fcm.getToken()

    // Listen to incoming messages
    this.fcm.listenToNotifications().pipe(
      tap(msg => {
        // show a toast
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: msg.body,
          duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
      })
    )
    .subscribe()
  }

}
```

*fcm.ts below*

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';


/*
  Generated class for the FcmProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class FcmProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,public firebaseNative: Firebase,
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    private platform: Platform) {
    console.log('Hello FcmProvider Provider');
  }

  async getToken() {

    let token;

    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken()
    } 

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();
      await this.firebaseNative.grantPermission();
    } 

    return this.saveTokenToFirestore(token)
  }

  private saveTokenToFirestore(token) {
    if (!token) return;

    const devicesRef = this.afs.collection('devices')

    const docData = { 
      token,
      userId: 'testUser',
    }

    return devicesRef.doc(token).set(docData)
  }

  listenToNotifications() {
    return this.firebaseNative.onNotificationOpen()
  }
}
```

*config.xml below*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.webwrapper.theapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>B13Wrapper</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="2.0.5" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://172.16.13.85:8100" sessionid="4a721959" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
</widget>
```